# new Date(1967, 9, 22) creates object pointing to October 21

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that creates the date object pointing to other date.

```
var date = new Date(1967, 9, 22)
```

result:

```
Sat Oct 21 1967 23:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
```

Does anybody knows why this happen?

Comment: try creating the date pointing to day 21 or 23. It works, the only day that I had problem is 22.

Comment: Also, the first month is 0 = January.

Comment: @bfavaretto: That's what I thought too, but the documentation says that [dates up to 100,000,000 days prior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Description) to Jan 1, 1970 should be valid too.

Comment: The problem is the day not the month. I know that 9 points to October but check the day, it changes from 22 to 21.

Comment: The range of month is from 0 to 11

Comment: @Cameron Yep, just read that. But Oct. 22, 1967 works for me in Chrome console, see http://i.stack.imgur.com/pSqME.png

Comment: Working fine for me in Firefox.  So you type `new Date(1967, 9, 22)` in your browser debug console and you get that "Oct 21" date?

Comment: Yep, I guess that is related to brazilian time-zone.

Comment: What is the result of `date.getDate()` and `date.getHours()`?

Comment: I strongly suspect it's due to the time zone, although the switchover date in Brazil in 1967 was October 31st: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=233&syear=1960

Comment: Notice that the time he's getting is `23:00`. When I use that assignment, I get `00:00`. It looks like it has something to do with the daylight savings time switch, so it's returning a time an hour early.

Comment: Does it still occur if you manually specify an hour, e.g. `new Date(1967, 9, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0)`?

Comment: @Cameron yes, the same problem:
new Date(1967, 9, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Sat Oct 21 1967 23:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess : the 21st of october was a daylight change day this year, like it was in 2012, so the hour changed from 00:00 directly to 01:00, hence when the Javascript engine gets 1967, 9, 22 at 00:00, it is an 'impossible' date, so it seems that the method used to get an existing date is to remove the time shift (one hour) : this way you get 1967, 9, 21 23:00, which is what you read on screen.

It tried with my own (french) daylight savings : i choosed the last daylight change of march, 31. At 2h00 it is 3h00. So 2h30 is an 'impossible' date.
When i type in Chrome :

```
new Date(2013, 2, 31, 2, 30, 00)
```

i read :

```
Sun Mar 31 2013 01:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

2h30 becomes 1h30.

Edit : following Cameron's idea, since some time shifts might last 1, 2, hour, or more, and might be in one direction or another, the safest way to get the same day of year when building a date is to have the hour set to 12. This should be javascript's default, in fact.

Details:
To be complete on this topic you have to know that very rarely some entire days are removed from the calendars, for various political or energy-related reasons. So if a 100.000% reliability is required, you have to test that the day/month of the Date object are the same as the day/month provided (!!).

Comment: In which case, adding an hour will create a date with the correct day/month/year (`new Date(1967, 9, 22, 1)`).

Comment: @Vincent Piel is right. I tested some other dates that have started the day light saving and got the same problem.